# why visual studio 2013 isn't returning a string from a method whilst using debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

My problem is that my return value seems to disappear after it has exited it's method.

```
public async Task<string> mMethod(){
    // My methods code (creates a string to be used as html is quite large)
    return htmlString;
}
```

when following through on the debugger this method will execute fine and the returned string is exactly what I expect it to be. My problem arises with it's invoking method

```
public async void setHtml(){
   String html = await mMethod(); // Break point here is triggered
   // code below this is never used, the application is almost in a state of limbo 
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for windows, I'm developing for windows 8.1. This is only happening when I am using debugger, if I start without debugging this problem doesn't happen. Does anyone know whats going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: `async` methods should be of return type `Task`, otherwise it's fire-and-forget.

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem. Plus it's also nothing to do the problem...

Comment: You probably have a deadlock. Check if you have used `.Wait()` or `.Result` on any of the tasks up in the call hierarchy.

Comment: The project doesn't build if you change eventhandlers to type Task. From what I can tell it seems to forget where the thread was meant to return to. I check the stack frame and it know but after the method it doesn't. @jeroen

Comment: @YK1  the method is used with the await key word my understanding was that wasn't needed if you use the keyword?

Comment: Yes, you should not use `Wait()` and `.Result`. Oh, but now I see you return `void`.

Comment: the problem method is not the void method it's mMethod() returning to setHtml(), setHtml never gets to finish ?

Comment: Check Tasks window after calling `mMethod()`.

Comment: Event methods are the only exception to async void methods. All others should be `async Task` unless deliberately different for some reason. Aside from that: too few code here to say anything about it.

Comment: @Jumpei There is nothing in there when it happens

Comment: Could you include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have found a soloution although I am not sure why this works if anyone does I would appreciate if they could explain it for me.

When calling mMethod() inserting Task.WaitAny(); above stopped this bug from happening.

```
public async void setHtml(){
    Task.WaitAny();
    String html = await mMethod();
    //Break point on this line will now activate
}
```

Comment: There is no way this could have fixed the problem: `Task.WaitAny()` without any parameters won't do anything. Though if you have a race condition, it's possible that calling it would make the bug show itself less frequently.

Comment: Well it has fixed the problem and it hasn't occurred in the 2 hours I have since been using the code and debugging through it.